# Attach Excel file to a Report Created in SSRS 2008

Tags: pdf, service, reporting-services, web

I'm trying to modify a web service which is creating PDF file from Crystal Reports.
The PDF printer is an Amyuni converter.
The Service is attaching Excel documents to the end of the Crystal Reports.
I have to redesign the web service to use instead of Crystal Reports SSRS 2008 Reports and I'm not sure if SSRS reports can attach an excel file.
Any help will be appreciated
Regards
Flo

Answer (score 1):

[Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/) allows you to concatenate the output of a printing process to an existing PDF file. So if you just want to have a PDF file containing the information from SSRS and the excel file, you could just print your SSRS report and save it in a temporary file. Then you can print your excel file using automation, or use the ["save as pdf" function from Excel 2007+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407651%28v=office.12%29.aspx#XLSavingWorkbookstoPDFandXPS_CodeIt) and concatenate to the temporary file mentioned before using Amyuni PDF Converter.

From [the documentation](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_Document_Converter/Document_Interface/Methods/Append.htm):

> The Appen and AppendEx methods append or concatenate a second PDF file
>   to a first one.

*Usual disclaimer applies.*